# Cakephp 3.0 change or remove wrapping div on input form

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to remove or change the wrapping div that CakePHP uses on its form helper.

When I use this code:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('contact', ['label' => false]);
```

The output is:

```
<div class="input text">
  <input type="text" id="contact" maxlength="255" name="contact">
</div>
```

And what I want is:

```
<div class="myOwnClass">
  <input type="text" id="contact" maxlength="255" name="contact">
</div>
```

I used to do that on CakePHP 2 adding more options to the input method, however on the latest CakePHP version this isn't working. Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Use FormHelper Templates

To change wrapping for **all inputs** in form use:

```
$this->Form->templates([
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="myOwnClass">{{content}}</div>'
]);
// or remove completely
$this->Form->templates([
    'inputContainer' => '{{content}}'
]);
// now get input with desired wrapping
echo $this->Form->input('contact', [
    'label' => false
]);
```

To change wrapping for **single input** use:

```
echo $this->Form->input('contact', [
    'templates' => [
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="myOwnClass">{{content}}</div>'
    ],
    'label' => false
]);
```

For complete reference on templates read: **[Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**

CakePHP 2 style of customizing the wrappings is not supported anymore in version 3. From migration guide:

> The div, before, after, between and errorMessage options have been
>   removed from input(). You can use templates to update the wrapping
>   HTML. The templates option allows you to override the loaded templates
>   for one input.

Comment: this is nice. but how do I point the templates to a file found in a plugin?

Comment: Just a heads up: a submit element, though still an input, [is controlled by `submitContainer` separately](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-submit-elements)

Answer (score 6):

I'm working with a UI purchased and there have been several problems with cakephp3. For me it is not so easy to remove the `<div>` initial, most to the solution provided here, after much testing:

```
echo $this->Form->control('username', [
  'templates'     => ['inputContainer' => '{{content}}'],
  "type"          => "text",
  "aria-invalid"  => "false",
  "aria-required" => "true",
  "class"         => "form-control valid",
  "placeholder"   => "Ingrese su usuario o email ...",
  "autocomplete"  => "on",
  'label'         => false
]);
```

the result

```
<input name="username" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="form-control valid" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario o email ..." autocomplete="on" id="username" type="text">
```

only adds an input tag (sorry for my Google-English)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a better way to define the templates global in the config folder:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user, array(
    "class" => "ui form", 
    "templates" => "semantic" // The filename in your config folder without .php
)); ?>
```

In the config folder create the file "semantic.php" (You can name it to whatever you want) with the content:

```
return array(
    "inputContainer" => '{{content}}' // Here the magic happens
);
```

Hope this helps!