# CakePHP 3 input type file design

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I want to set span before input type file. Here is my existing code.

```
<?= $this->Form->input('logo', ['onchange'=>'onFileImage(this);',
                                'label' => false,
                                'type' => 'file',
                                'class'=>'']);?>
<lable class="inva_img"></lable>
```

I want the output to resemble the code below.

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
  <span>Choose file</span>
  <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" onchange="onFileImage(this);" />
</span>
```

Comment: Seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686111

Comment: @AlimonKarim yes it on CakePHP.

Comment: Please mention your version , which version are you using ?

Comment: @AlimonKarim cakephp 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by below code

```
<?php  
    echo $this->Form->input('logo', [
            'templates' => [
                'inputContainer' => '<span class="input file required btn btn-default input {{type}}{{required}}"><span>Choose file</span>{{content}}</span>',
            ],
            'onchange'=>'onFileImage(this);',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'type' => 'file',
            'label' => false
    ]);
?>
```

For details please see ndm [ans.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140362/input-wrapper-div-class-in-cakephp-3-0-0)

Comment: Thanks your answer ok. I need little more suggestion before applied your code it looks like http://screencast.com/t/r3oAjluv4 after apply it displaying http://screencast.com/t/Iujh3YG6Ig can You suggest me how can I get that?

Comment: Is it after choice file button ? I think you may miss echo. check you have added code 

<?= ?>  or <?php echo ..... ?>

Comment: I added echo and <?php ?> but no improvement. It's not displaying "no file choosen"

Comment: Oh ! understood  !! just change your span class 

<span class="input file required btn btn-default> I think now you will get your desire output.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
  <span>Choose file</span>
  <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" onchange="onFileImage(this);" />
</span>
```

Just replace `<input>` tag field with cakephp standard keeping others code unchanged. Here is the conversion:

```
   <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                <span>Choose file</span>
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input(
                        'logo', array(
                    'id' => 'logo',
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'onchange' => 'onFileImage(this);'
                        )
                );
                ?>
            </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the before/after options

```
echo $this->Form->input('field_name', array(
    'before' => '-before-',
    'after' => '-after-',
    'between' => '-between-'
));
```

read more of this in cakephp [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this for cakephp2:

```
<?php
 $this->Form->input('logo', ['onchange'=>'onFileImage(this);',
                                  'label' => false,
                                  'before' => '<span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span>Choose file</span>',
                                  'after' => '</span>',

                                  'type' => 'file',
                                  'class'=>'']);
```

I hope that there is similar concept for cakephp3

HTH.